# Is there a Drupal module for importing text and images?

Tags: drupal

I'm very new to Drupal, and am wondering if there's an API that external programs can call to transfer text and images directly into my Drupal site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  There are several ways to accomplish this in Drupal:

1. If you're doing a one-time import, try the [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) module --- this lets you import content from a CSV file.
2. If you want your Drupal site to provide a web-based API to which new content can be POSTed (via, for example, XMLRPC), check out the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/Services) module.
3. If you want your Drupal site to periodically retrieve content from other sites (RSS feeds, for example), check out [FeedAPI](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi).
4. If you want to write your own PHP code to create new content, check out [this article](http://acquia.com/blog/migrating-drupal-way-part-i-creating-node) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by having a module for importing text, but there is one specifically for images: the [Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/image) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows users with proper permissions to upload images into Drupal. Thumbnails and additional sizes are created automatically.
>
> Images could be posted individually to the front page, included in stories or grouped in galleries.

Importing text can be performed directly as one of the other existing entity types.